# writing file data directly to disk/db with blobs (plone.app.blob/Archetypes, and plone.namedfile)

Tags: blob, plone, dexterity, archetypes

I have several pieces of data that need to be merged into one file (ATContentTypes blob file, Plone 4.1). The total amount of data is likely to be quite large so I really don't want to have to load it all into memory, concatenate it, and do something like o.setFile(data). If I were writing directly to the file system I could just do open(myfile, 'a') and write to it, but I'm not clear how I could do that with a blob supported content type. All of the docs and tests I've been able to look at just have it being set with a str or in-memory StringIO. Is there a way to append to this field without loading the whole thing into memory?

Similarly, I've also looked at using Dexterity with a plone.namedfile NamedBlobFile. It looks like that field just has a 'data' attribute that is basically a string. How could I append to that without loading the whole thing into memory?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old and the product has never been officially released, but it can help you: ore.bigfile.

It's well explained in this blog article: http://blog.jazkarta.com/2010/09/21/handling-large-files-in-plone-with-ore-bigfile/